# The use of the word "reinforce" in context

Tags: word-choice

Let's say I tought students some new grammar on the last class, and now I am going to give them a task to do for helping memorize the grammar. Could *reinforce* be approoriate in the following sentence? If not, then what is a natural word for saying that?

> I am going to give a task to **reinforce** the already learnt grammar.

By the way, is it *in the last class* or *on the last class*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that would be fine. In full you could say "*I am going to give you a task to **reinforce** the grammar you already learnt **in** the last class*"